# how to pause and resume voice recording in android using cordova media plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, audio-recording, cordova-media-plugin

I'm using angularjs in visual studio.using cordova media plugin startRecord() and stopRecord() is working but not able to pause and resume recording.I'm not using media capture plugin as i don't have default recorder installed.

This is my code:

```
var audurl = '///storage/emulated/0/New/';
audurl += 'Voice_' + '.amr';
var mediaRec;
function recordAudio() {
  mediaRec = new Media(audurl, onSuccess, onError);
  mediaRec.startRecord();
}
function pauseAudio() {
  mediaRec = new Media(audurl, onSuccess, onError);
  mediaRec.pauseRecord();
}
```

thanks...

Comment: [This](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#quick-example-7) example shows everything you want to know. Although its pauses and resumes automatically (by using setTimeout) it is shown of how to resume recording.

Comment: Can I pause and resume on button click.

Comment: I think as per Documentation pause and resume work's in iOS only.

Comment: I think as per Documentation pause and resume work's in iOS only: On the first glance yes, but when you take a look on android-source code [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/src/android/AudioHandler.java) pause and resume are supported by android as well.

Comment: Can I pause and resume on button click: Yes, of course. You have to define one click-handler that calls pauseRecord and one that calls resumeRecord.

Comment: But after I click button calling pauseRecord() recording continues, pause not working.

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: var audurl = "///storage/emulated/0/New/";
        audurl += 'Voice_' + '.amr';
        var mediaRec;
        
function recordAudio() {
            mediaRec = new Media(audurl, onSuccess, onError);
            mediaRec.startRecord();
        }

        function pauseAudio() {
           mediaRec = new Media(audurl, onSuccess, onError);
             mediaRec.pauseRecord();
           
        }function resumeAudio() {
           mediaRec = new Media(audurl, onSuccess, onError);
            mediaRec.resumeRecord();
        };
calling these functions in ng-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my phone the method *[media.resumeRecord](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#mediaresumerecord)* was not available, although in this [soure-code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/src/android/AudioHandler.java) it is defined. Nevertheless you can take advantage of all other methods, like `startRecord` and `stopRecord`, to rebuild a kind of  resumeRecord function, as it is done in a handler below:

```
var myRecordHandler = function () {

  // ALL RECORDED FILES ARE SAVED IN THIS ARRAY
  var recordedAudioFiles = [];

  // REMEMBER POSITION WHEN PLAYING IS STOPPED
  var currentPosition = {index:0,shift:0};

  // PAUSE-MODE
  var paused = false;

  // SET A SPECIFC DIRECTORY WHERE THE FILES ARE STORED INTO
  // DEFAULT: ''
  this.setDirectory = function(dir) {this.dir=dir;};

  // SET FILENAME
  // DEFAULT: recoredFilesX
  this.setFilename = function(filename) {this.filename=filename;};

  // SET MIME/Type of THE FILES; 
  // DEFAULT: mp3
  this.setFileType = function(type) {this.filetype=type;};

  // GET ALL RECORED FILES 
  this.getAllFiles = function() {return recordedAudioFiles;};

  // STOP/PAUSE RECORDED FILES
  var handleRecordedFileHold = function () {
    for (var r = 0; r < recordedAudioFiles.length; r++) {

      var recordedAudioFile = recordedAudioFiles[r];

      if(recordedAudioFile.isBeingRecorded){
         if(paused)recordedAudioFile.media.pause();
         else recordedAudioFile.media.stop();
         continue;
      }

      recordedAudioFile.duration = new Date().getTime() - recordedAudioFile.startTime;
      // call release to free this created file so that it could get deleted for instance
      recordedAudioFile.media.stopRecord();
      recordedAudioFile.media.release();
      recordedAudioFile.isBeingRecorded = true;
    }
  } 

  // START RECORDING
  this.startAudioRecording = function() {

    paused = false;
    handleRecordedFileHold();

    var dir = this.dir ? this.dir : '';
    var filename = this.filename ? this.filename : 'recoredFiles';
    var type = this.filetype ? this.filetype : 'mp3';

    var src = dir + filename + (recordedAudioFiles.length + 1) + '.' + type;
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, 
       function () {
         console.log('recordAudio():Audio Success');
       }, 
       function (err) {
         console.log('recordAudio():Audio Error: ' + err.code);
    });
    recordedAudioFiles.push({
      media: mediaRec,
      startTime: new Date().getTime()
    });
    mediaRec.startRecord();
  } 

  // PAUSE RECORDING
  this.pauseRecoredFiles = function () {
    if(recordedAudioFiles.length){
       paused = true;
       clearTimeout(currentPosition.timeout);
       handleRecordedFileHold();
       var recoredMedia = recordedAudioFiles[currentPosition.index].media;
       recoredMedia.getCurrentPosition(
           function (position) {
              currentPosition.shift = position;
           },
           function (e) {
              console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
           }
       );
    }
  } 

  // PLAY RECORD
  this.playRecordedFiles = function () {
    handleRecordedFileHold();
    var playNextFile = function () {
      var recoredMedia = recordedAudioFiles[currentPosition.index];
      if (recoredMedia) {
        if(paused){
          recoredMedia.media.seekTo(currentPosition.shift*1000);
          paused = false;
        }
        recoredMedia.media.play();
        currentPosition.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
          currentPosition.index++;
          recoredMedia.media.stop();
          playNextFile();
        }, recoredMedia.duration ? recoredMedia.duration : 0);
      }
      else{
        paused = false;
        currentPosition.index = currentPosition.shift = 0;
      }
    };
    playNextFile();
  } 

  // RESET PLAY
  this.stopRecordedFiles = function () {
    currentPosition.index = currentPosition.shift = 0;
    clearTimeout(currentPosition.timeout);
    handleRecordedFileHold();
  }

  // REMOVE ALL RECORDED FILES 
  this.removeRecordedFiles = function() {
    paused = false;
    currentPosition.index = currentPosition.shift = 0;
    clearTimeout(currentPosition.timeout);
    handleRecordedFileHold();
    recordedAudioFiles = [];
  }

};

var handler = new myRecordHandler();

// you can use this handler in your functions like this:
function recordAudio() {
  // records one track and stops former track if there is one
  handler.startAudioRecording();
}

function playAudio() {
  handler.playRecordedFiles();
}

function pauseAudio() {
  handler.pauseRecoredFiles();
}

function resumeAudio() {
  pauseAudio();
  recordAudio();
}

function stopAudio() {
  handler.stopRecordedFiles();
}
```

---

Although **I could not test** your directory/filenames, because I do not have this directory created on my phone, these methods might help you to to store your files in a specific directory as well as with certain filenames:

```
handler.setDirectory('__YOUR_DIR__');

handler.setFilename('__YOUR_FILENAME__');

handler.setFileType('__YOUR_FILETYPE__');
```

Comment: also tried like this but same problem.Also if ID generated each time,how stopRecord() works.

Comment: Have you already played a recorded audio file again? Is there a red-LED light glowing while recording? These methods should work otherwise you have to inform the developers themselves, sorry.

Comment: yes,but there is no led light glowing.Actually i'm not using any default recorder,i have created a UI to do this

Comment: Ok, the red-light was just an idea, some devices do have such lights.

Comment: Hope my little handler helps you. Just for information: call playAudio and pauseAudio with some delay to see that your recorded audio is truly appended one after one.

Comment: And if it fulfills your request, then please mark this anwer as right, thank you.

Comment: stopAudio() not working.when i click stop it stores with file size 0 B but if i goes back without click stop it shows the actual file size and play also.

Comment: Thanks, it shoudl be much better now. Pause/Stop should also do what they are expected to do now. Have fun!

Comment: But stopAudio() is not working.ok.let me check.thanks

Comment: No still the same issue..when file is saved its size is 0 B.

Comment: It seems that there is some strange behavior in this plugin. Unfortunately there is still not answer as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40156481/2401386) nevertheless I recommend you to track this question, it might be answered soon. If all other functionalities work then please mark this answer as right, as it fulfills your original request. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, when I've more time I take a look for this other question as well.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Comment: can i start a new post on this?

Comment: Of course, but please no copy of the former post, as this happens on an android phone not on an iOS-phone.